# My branches have diveregd after a "squash and merge". How do I fix that?

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request, squash

I did a 'squash and merge' to close a PR. Although all the changes are now present in `master`, it still says the branches have diverged and there are still changes ahead and behind.

```
This branch is 1 commit ahead, 28 commits behind develop.
```

How do I fix this? The 28 commits behind are the ones which were squashed during 'squash and merge'. I've been through https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-merge-methods-on-github#squashing-your-merge-commits , but could not find any connection.

I assumed (wrongly ?) that 'squash and merge' would do a fast forward merge to prevent the divergence. I didn't want all the commits from `develop` to move to `master`, which is why I did a "squash and merge", instead of rebasing. I think I'm missing something about squash and merge.

I've gone through similar questions on SO, but it ends up with suggestions to do an interactive rebase and squash commits before merging to `master`. But I don't want to lose the history in `develop`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your stated requirements are:

1) There should be only one commit added to master

2) All commits should remain on the develop branch (no loss of history)

3) The new commit on the master branch should be related to the original commits, so that git doesn't think they've diverged

The closest git will come to meeting these three requirements simultaneously is a simple merge.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge develop
```

If you do this, it is true that when git displays `master`'s history it will, by default, include the commits from `develop`; you can avoid that using the `--first-parent` option to commands ilke `git log`.

The actual commit graph ends up looking like

```
o -- x -- x -- M <--(master)
 \            /
  x --- x -- x <--(develop)
```

so `M` (the merge commit) is added to `master`, and it "remembers" its relationship to the full history on `develop`.

In fact the whole difference in doing a "squash merge" (as you noted) is that `M` "forgets" its relationship to `develop` - the 2nd parent isn't recorded.

A `rebase` workflow sacrifices requirement (1) - and also requires rewriting of the commits in a way that creates new intermediate commits that may or may not be in a working state - in favor of a linear history.

"Squash-and-merge" could "fix" the limitations of `rebase`, but it sacrifices requirement (3) - and unless you keep `develop` around as its own diverged branch forever, you then lose requirement (2).

Personally I find those costs too high when the only payoff is a linear history; some people really seem to love that linearity and swear it's easier to understand, but I don't value it so much.

Either way, though, those are the trade-offs each team needs to make is deciding on a change integration strategy.

Answer (score 10):

> How do I fix this?

It's only sort-of fixable.  You're normally supposed to just delete the branch entirely now.  You can then create a *new* branch, even one that's still named `develop`.  It's then a different branch, even though it's the same name.

This sequence of commands *may* fix it, but *be very careful* and make sure you understand each one:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard develop
git push --force-with-lease origin master
```

The `git reset --hard` command will throw out any *uncommitted* work, so be extra-careful any time you are using this.

I'll give some alternatives below.  There are many options, with different effects, especially on any other people who might be using the GitHub repository.  If *you* are the only person using the GitHub repository, you can do whatever you like.

In any case, remember: this is the goal of squash-and-merge: to *kill off the branch*.  The idea is that after this squash-and-merge, you'll delete the branch name and give up all 28 commits forever.  The squash-and-merge made one *new* commit that contains the same *work* as the 28 earlier commits, so the one new commit is the new-and-improved *replacement* for those 28 commits.

To understand what you're doing, read on.

#### To really "get" Git, you need to draw graphs

> I assumed (wrongly ?) that 'squash and merge' would do a fast forward merge to prevent the divergence. I didn't want all the commits from `develop` to move to `master`, which is why I did a "squash and merge", instead of rebasing. I think I'm missing something about squash and merge.

Yes.  GitHub throws an extra wrinkle in here, too—or maybe, takes a wrinkle you want *away*, depending on how you look at it.  We need a little side bit first.

Git is all about *commits*.  These commits are formed into a *graph*, specifically a ***D***irected **A**cyclic **G**raph or *DAG*.  The way this works is actually remarkably simple:

- Every commit has a unique hash ID.  This hash ID is, in effect, the true name of the commit.
- Every commit is made of two parts: its data—a snapshot of all of your files—and some *metadata*, information about the commit itself, such as who made it (your name and email address), when (date-and-time-stamps), and why (your log message).  Most of that metadata is just to show you when you look at the commit, but one piece of information is crucial for Git itself: each commit lists the raw hash IDs of its *parent* commits.

Most commits just have one single parent.  When something contains the hash ID of a commit, we say that that something *points to* the commit.  So a commit *points to* its parent.  If we have a chain of commits all in a row, we can draw them like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where the uppercase letters stand in for actual hash IDs.  The *latest* commit is commit `H`.  It points to its parent, which came just before it: commit `G`.  Commit `G` points to its parent `F`, and so on.

A *branch name*, in Git, is simply a name that points to the *latest* commit:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
```

When we make a new branch, what we're really doing is telling Git: *make a new name that points to some existing commit*.  So if we make a branch `develop` now, we get this:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop, master
```

Now we need to know which *name* we're actually using, so we attach the special name `HEAD` to that name:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), master
```

When we make *new* commits, we just have Git write out the commit—this computes the new commit's unique hash ID—with a snapshot and with its parent set to the *current* commit (`H` at the moment):

```
...--G--H
         \
          I
```

What happens to the names now is also very simple: the one that `HEAD` is attached to, Git writes the new commit's hash ID there.  All the other ones: nothing happens at all.  So our new graph is:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

As we add more commits, they just keep growing the branch:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

(Here `develop` is `3 ahead` of `master`.)

There's one other key thing to realize: *commits `G` and `H`, and all the ones before those that are on `master`, are also on `develop`.*  In other words, commits are often on *more than one branch*.  (This is a weird thing about Git: many other version control systems *do not* work this way.)

#### True merging and fast-forwarding

At this point, we can run `git merge`, locally in our own repositories (but not on GitHub) using:

```
git checkout master; git merge develop
```

Git will take a short-cut—the *fast-forward* thing you mentioned.  We'll get back to this in a moment.

Alternatively, we can run `git merge --no-ff develop`, forcing Git to make a true merge.  **This is what the "merge" button on GitHub will do, so let's look at it.**  A "true" merge always makes a new *merge commit*.  True merges are *required* if the two branches have *diverged:* for instance, if we had:

```
       o--o   <-- branch1
      /
...--o
      \
       o--o   <-- branch2
```

and we wanted to merge them, we would be forced to use a true merge.  That's not what we have; we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

(Remember, we're on `master` now: we did a `git checkout master` so `H` is the *current* commit.  `K` is the last commit on `develop`.)

GitHub just forces a true merge in *all* cases, including our own simple one.  To do a true merge, Git finds a *merge base* commit—which in this case is commit `H`—and compares that merge base twice, once against the current commit `H`, and once against commit `K`.

Obviously, commit `H` matches commit `H`.  So there are no changes on our side to carry forward.  We only want any changes that *they* made, going from `H` to `K`.  The result will be the same as the snapshot in `K`.  But we are forcing the merge, so Git makes a new merge commit, which I'll call `M` for `merge`:

```
...--G--H---------M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \       /
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

The thing that makes `M` special—that makes it a merge—is that it has not just one parent, but two.  Its *first* parent is commit `H`, which is where we were a moment ago.  Its second parent is commit `K`.  Its *snapshot* is the result of combining the work we did on `H`-vs-`H`—no work at all—with the work they did on `H`-vs-`K`, so the new merge commit's snapshot matches commit `K`'s snapshot, but the end result is this new merge commit.

**If we allow Git to do a fast forward instead of merging**, this is what we'd get:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop, master (HEAD)
```

(which allows us to take the kink out of the drawing, though I didn't bother).  Git calls this a fast-forward merge, even though there's no actual merging happening.  Unfortunately **GitHub's buttons do not allow us to do a fast-forward merge**.

#### A squash merge is a true merge but without a second parent

If we did a true merge, we would get this graph:

```
...--G--H---------M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \       /
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

Commit `M` would have the same snapshot as commit `K` and would have two parents, `H` and `K`.

Doing a squash merge, we get instead this graph:

```
...--G--H---------S   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

Commit `S` has the same snapshot as commit `K`, but has only one parent, `H`.  The idea here is that you want a single ordinary commit that has the same effect as all the commits you'd made on `develop`.  This single commit is the new-and-improved way to do the job.  The old way—the old `I-J-K` commits—are no longer useful and should be abandoned; eventually, some time after 30 days or more, your Git will delete them for real.  So you just run a force-delete of the *name* `develop`, producing:

```
...--G--H---------S   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I--J--K   [abandoned]
```

If you like, you can now create the *name* `develop` again, but this time pointing to commit `S`:

```
...--G--H--S   <-- develop, master (HEAD)
         \
          I--J--K   [abandoned]
```

#### The purpose of branch names is to let you (and Git) find commits

Note that as we manipulate the graph to add commits, we move the branch names.  The branch names *always* point to the *latest* commit.  This is how Git defines things to work.

We can, however, force a branch name to move anywhere we like.  If we have a particular branch checked out, as in this state:

```
...--G--H--S   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

we can use `git reset --hard` to switch commits and, as it were, shove commit `S` out of the way:

```
          S   [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

Note that commit `S` still *exists*.  It's just that by starting with the name `master`, we find commit `H`, then we work backwards and find commit `G`, and so on.  We never move forwards, so we can't *get to* commit `S`.  It's been abandoned, just as commits `I-J-K` would be if we deleted the name `develop`.

If you save the raw hash ID of a commit somewhere—e.g., write it down on paper, or on a whiteboard, or cut and paste it into a file—you can use that hash ID later, directly, to have Git find that commit.  If it's still *in* the repository (which it will be for at least 30 days by default), you can find it that way.  But you won't find it by most ordinary `git log` and other Git commands.

Note that if a commit is on *more than one* branch—e.g., if we have:

```
...--P   <-- branch1
      \
       Q   <-- branch2
        \
         R   <-- branch3
```

and we delete the name `branch2`—it may still be find-able.  The result of deleting the *name* `branch2` is:

```
...--P   <-- branch1
      \
       Q--R   <-- branch3
```

after all.  Commit `Q` still exists either way, but this time, we *can* find it, by starting with `R` and working backwards.

This is why it is important to draw the graph, or part of it.  The commits that you can *find*, by starting at some name and working backwards, are the commits that you will be able to find tomorrow, too—assuming you don't move the names around, that is.

#### This gives you two options so far

You can either keep your squash-merge commit and forget the others, by *deleting* the name `develop` entirely:

```
...--o--o--S   <-- master
         \
          o--o--...--o   [was develop; 28 commits, all abandoned]
```

or you can form your own local Git graph to look like this:

```
          S   <-- origin/master
         /
...--o--o   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          o--o--...--o   <-- develop, origin/develop
```

Note that your `master` identifies the commit one step before commit `S`.  The name `origin/master`, which is your Git's local copy of the GitHub `master`, points to commit `S`.

If your `master` *already* looks like this, you're already set.  If your `master` looks like this:

```
          S   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
         /
...--o--o
         \
          o--o--...--o   <-- develop, origin/develop
```

you would run `git reset --hard HEAD~1` to move it back one to make it look like the first drawing.

Now that *your* (local) Git repository is set up the right way, you must tell the Git over at GitHub to move *its* `master` back one step.  To do that, you need to use `git push --force` or `git push --force-with-lease`:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin master
```

The difference between the two is that `--force-with-lease` has their Git (the one on GitHub) check that what you think they have as their `master`, they really do have as their `master`.  So `--force-with-lease` adds a bit of safety vs the simpler `--force`, if someone else also works with this other repository.

A normal everyday `git push` has your Git call up another Git—in this case, the one on GitHub—and figure out if you have new commits for them.  If you do have new commits for them, your Git sends those over.  Then, at the end, your Git makes a polite request to them: *If it's OK, please set your branch name ______ to commit hash _______*.  Git will fill in both blanks: the name is the branch name you use, i.e., `master` in `git push origin master`, and the hash ID is the hash ID that name currently means in *your* Git.

A force-push does the same thing except the final request is not polite at all: it's a demand, *Set your branch name _______ to ________!*

The other Git involved in a `git push` will accept a polite request if it won't *lose* any commits.  In this case, your request or command is designed specifically to make them *lose* commit `S`.  That is, *they* have:

```
...--o--o--S   <-- master
         \
          o--o--...--o   <-- develop
```

and you want them to shove `S` out of the way and make their `master` point to the commit before `S`.  So you will need some kind of forceful push.

#### You can *revert* the squash-merge, then rebase

The `git revert` command works by adding a new commit that undoes the effect of a previous commit.  Since this *adds* commits, Gits are happy to take the new commit.  This particular method is a little silly here, so while I'll draw the effect, it's probably not something you want:

```
...--o--H--S--U   <-- master
         \
          o--o--...--o   <-- develop
```

I've given the starting point commit `H` for `develop` a name here.  The reason is that the *snapshot* in commit `U`, the undo for `S`, will match the snapshot in commit `H`.

You can now use `git rebase` to *copy* the whole series of commits that were on `develop` to a new series of commits.  These new commits have different hash IDs and different parent linkages, but have the same *snapshots* as before:

```
                o--o--...--o   <-- develop (HEAD)
               /
...--o--H--S--U   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          o--o--...--o   <-- origin/develop
```

You're now in the same sort of situation as you were in before you accidentally made commit `S`.  You would have to force-push your updated `develop` to GitHub.  (And then, of course, you still have to merge everything!)

#### You can go ahead and do a real merge

You can leave squash commit `S` in place and do a real merge:

```
git fetch                           # if needed
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only origin/master   # if needed
```

so that you have:

```
...--G--H--S   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
         \
          I--...--R   <-- develop, origin/develop
```

and then:

```
git merge develop
```

to produce:

```
             ,--------<-- origin/master
            .
...--G--H--S--------M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \         /
          I--...--R   <-- develop, origin/develop
```

You can now `git push origin master` to get them to accept merge commit `M`, giving you:

```
...--G--H--S--------M   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
         \         /
          I--...--R   <-- develop, origin/develop
```

in your own local Git repository.

#### You can delete S, fast-forward-merge your `develop`, and force-push

Finally, this is probably what you'd *like* to see in your personal, local Git repository, before doing any force pushes:

```
          S   <-- origin/master
         /
...--G--H--I--...--R   <-- develop, master (HEAD), origin/develop
```

This is perhaps what you have though:

```
          S   <-- origin/master
         /
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I--...--R   <-- develop, origin/develop
```

or maybe you now have:

```
          S   <-- master (HEAD). origin/master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          I--...--R   <-- develop, origin/develop
```

To get what you want, in *either* case, you can just:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard develop
```

Since your `develop` currently points to commit `R`, this checks out commit `R`, makes your `master` point to commit `R`, and leaves you with the graph you want.  You can then use a force-push:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin master
```

to send any commits you have that they don't (none, they already have all these commits) and command them: *I think your `master` identifies commit `S`.  If so, make it identify commit `R` now!*  They will usually obey this command and you will have what you want.